# How to import an SFDC Report CSV export file in Numbers on Apple's iCloud?

Tags: data-export, excel

Using Numbers on a Mac for editing my spreadsheets, but unable to find a way of downloading a report (export) from Salesforce and doing the following with Numbers: open, edit, and save.

How to open and save a CSV file in Numbers?

Answer (score 4):

There should be export options when you're viewing a report. You should be able to export any report into CSV or XLS format and open in Numbers.

Comment: I have of course tried this, but the xls version that downloads doesn't open correctly in Number, it opens as an XML file, i.e., all data in one column. The CSV file opens straight up in the browser, maybe it is my browser config, I'll check that.

Comment: Rather than double-clicking, which will open in the default app, you might right click -> Open In... or just import from Numbers directly.

Answer (score 1):

**Open File:** If the file has a `CSV` extension, not `TXT`, you should have the following options to open the file:

- Right click and open it with Numbers,
- Drop it on the Numbers icon in the dock, or
- Open Numbers & drop the file into it.

** If it has a `TXT` extension, try changing it to `CSV`.

---

**Export File:**

1. List item
2. Open file,
3. Click: File > Export
4. Select: FileType = "`CSV`"
5. Name & Save File

[image]

**(Numbers 2.1 on OSX 10.6.8)**